# iOS 6 Banshee Syncing

Tags: banshee, ios

I got banshee to detect my ipod and it do

The sync but the new songs simply just don't pop up on the music app. on the program on my ubuntu everything looks fine.
its super annoying

I have a ipod touch 5g running the latest version 6.1.3

please assist me with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://banshee.fm/support/faq/

> iPods - most iPods and iOS devices should work with Banshee. Apple frequently updates the database format the devices use by upgrading iTunes, so it's recommended to use Banshee exclusively to manage your iPod, or not at all. Importing music from an iPod managed with iTunes should be fine, though.

Basically, quit updating your phone with iTunes. Banshee will catch up to the DB version being used and you'll be able to sync.